# Cómo puedo ocultar el Api Key de google autocomplete para que no se pueda ver del lado del cliente en react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, google-api

Cómo puedo esconder mi api Key de google para evitar que se vea del lado del cliente?

[image: Screenshot]

en el index.html estoy usando el script, pero hay alguna otra manera de utilizar Google autocomplete?

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: podrías hacerlo con variables de ambiente de react js o obtener la información con php, y mostrar solo lo que quieres usar : )

Comment: NO es posible ocultar cualquier cosa que esté del lado del cliente, aún cuando ofusques el código o recurras a miles de trucos, siempre habrá formas de encontrarla, si se quiere encontrar, puesto que está del lado del cliente. Como medida de seguridad tú puedas restringir el uso de esa API a determinadas URLs, IPs, aplicaciones móviles (y aún así no es 100% seguro). [Revisa esta respuesta para más detalles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625963/5587982). Una forma más segura sería en el servidor, y acceder a los datos a través de un servicio REST. No sé si te convenga de ese modo.

Comment: yo encuentro que con php  sería una mejor opción

Comment: No se puede ocultar, pero la que debes cuidar es la clave privada. que es la que usas solo en el lado del servidor.